# Pixel RGB values are all zero

Tags: html, canvas, rgb

I want to iterate through pixels of canvas and get their colors as RGB but all pixels have 0,0,0 RGB value even though there is an image on canvas.

Here is my code; (my test image is not seen in jsfiddle)

http://jsfiddle.net/mwPfa/2/

```
for(i = 400; i < 1000; i += 4) {
      red = imageData.data[i];
      green = imageData.data[i + 1];
      blue = imageData.data[i + 2];
      alpha = imageData.data[i + 3];
      console.log(red + "," + green + "," + blue + "," + alpha);
    }
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mwPfa/3/ working example

Comment: Thanks. When the applyPaint() is in the img's onload it's working fine. But why it should be there?

Comment: Your applyPaint() relies on the image being loaded.  The image is fully loaded when image.onload is called but the image is not fully loaded where you originally placed applyPaint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

working example - http://jsfiddle.net/mwPfa/3/

These were few things to mention:

1. window.onload - in jsfiddle you dont need to use it.
2. becouse of CORS, if you want to load image form external domain in jsfiddle, you have to use image that supports it and load in with `img.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";` - not every image will work here.
3. if you want to access image data - you HAVE to wait until image is loaded, so draw image and access the data only in onload handler. You dont want to access canvas data before image was loaded... It works sometimes, but you want stable code, that works everytime everwhere, don't you?
4. RGB with values 0,0,0 means **valid** black color, so make sure you don't test image with black top-left corner.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely because your canvas is *tainted* and the web browser security does not allow you to read it's data. This is because of cross-domain security: you are loading images or videos from other domain and drawing them on the canvas. If there were no cross-domain security you could e.g. steal users Facebook photos and such.

Mozilla Developer Network has an excellent article how to deal with the issue

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image

However, my suggestion is that if possible load your HTML pages and images from the same domain to avoid the CORS issues.

Comment: I'm not using a server, only working with html, js and png files on my machine. I can see the image, but when reading its pixels they all have the value of 0s.

Comment: That's probabl the problem. Use a development web server like http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/tech-tip-really-simple-http-server-python - file:// protocol has a lot of issues which do not affect the real websites.