# PIXI js - Pixel Data is Zero

Tags: html5-canvas, pixi.js

I'm currently working on a little game written in JS using Pixi.js(https://github.com/pixijs). One Problem has occured currently, I'm trying to implement pixel exact collision between shapes, while I was programing a little I noticed that all the pixel RBGA values of my images are just 0. 
I searched on the web but for a while but the only reason for those Problems I could find was that the canvas was tainted because of CORS([Pixel RGB values are all zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24261190/pixel-rgb-values-are-all-zero)).

But this can't be the reason in my case because I created the sprites myself, I'm not loading them from other (any) domains or something like that.

Could this be a problem with the images? How do I avoid that? I will append some code that works if I use other images (some images I downloaded for tests).

```
const app = new PIXI.Application({width: 500, height: 500});
document.body.appendChild(app.view);
PIXI.loader.add("sprites/test.png")
.load(() => {
 let img =  new PIXI.Sprite(PIXI.loader.resources["sprites/test.png"].texture);
 app.stage.addChild(img);
 console.log(app.renderer.extract.pixels(img));
});
```

Edit: I tried getting the RGBA values using a short Java Program btw, same problem. Every single value is zero.

Comment: Have you checked that you are loading the images from the same exact domain? For example www.example.com is different than example.com.

Comment: I don't load them from any domain if I understand your answer correctly.

Comment: any other ideas?